# insert values in the last column for my table from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to insert values in the last column for my table from another table but am getting error ERROR:

> null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: 
>   Failing row contains (ddf1caf0-26c2-49e1-8a73-64227eae1f50, null,
>   null, null, null, null, 2532).

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please provide some information about the tables. If a constraint is failing the data you want to insert isn't apropriate. Maybe you could first set default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to update the column `subsystem` of the table `software_instances` with values of the column `sub` of the table `temp_subsystem`:

```
update software_instances si
set subsystem = ts.sub
from temp_subsystem ts
where ts.module = si.module
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions to this issue

1. make sure the value you are selecting have the `name` value populated.
   Add `where name!=null` in the select query

or

2. alter the `software_instance` table , to accept null values for `name` column.

   ALTER TABLE SOFTWARE_INSTANCES ALTER COLUMN NAME DROP NOT NULL